# How do modern.ie updates work for modern apps in the windows insider preview?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, microsoft-edge

If you download an app that's targeted for windows 10 but requires a certain update that adds say a css feature to edge / winRT . Will you need to update to run the app?

Comment: Modern Windows 10 JavaScript apps don't run in a browser. They're native applications.

Comment: Sorry I meant what version of chakra in regards to edge or IE

Comment: You're asking for a prediction (what will they do?), and questions asking for speculation are not appropriate here.

Comment: If the app requires a certain update, then ostensibly you would need to update to run the app.

Answer (score 1):

if the app is using a feature that it has not implemented yet then you will need to update the code accordingly to support it otherwise that feature will crash. if the feature is based on web standards it should work on both IE11 and Edge as both support standards while IE has support for the older rendering engine.